# Does Eclipse support C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Does Eclipse support c/c++? I've been coding with Eclipse (Java) for a while now and i'm starting to learn C++ but i can't get Eclipse to work with C++.  I downloaded ""Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers"" from Eclipse.org, but it didn't work.  I don't want to use visual studio..Please help me out.

Basically, i can't create new project, class, etc.. When i clicked File --> New --> it shows "No Applicable Items"

Thank you.

Comment: What does "but it didn't work" mean?

Comment: OK, just take a deep breath and think for a minute: Is it plausibe that "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers" does *not* support C++?

Comment: The short answer is obviously yes.

Comment: I'm sorry about the details.  Basically, i can't create new project, class, etc.. When i clicked File --> New --> it shows "<No Applicable Items>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "No applicable items" message most likely means you're still using a Java perspective, so it can't open a C project. You need to change to the C/C++ perspective.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be helpful to explain how to change the perspective.

Comment: There's too much negativity (`votes--;`) Curious if the people who hold other members' answers to such a high standard apply the same to their own. Should user3311654 wipe op's butt too? Here, have it back...`votes++;`